# How to set the page size while opening the window?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using ASP.NET and C# and I am using window.open() for opening the window.Now i need to set the width of that page in that window.

I am using this code on buttonclick event.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "oncl", "<script language=javascript>window.open('Print.aspx','PrintMe','width=900,resizable=1,scrollbars=1');</script>");
```

The width inside the script is only setting the widow width. But i want to set the width of the page.

Is it possible?

Thanks..

Edit:

Sorry I didn't mention it before.I am writing the content into print.aspx dynamically.That i am using this code for fill the page.

```
    Page pg = new Page();
    pg.EnableEventValidation = false;
    HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();
    pg.Controls.Add(frm);
    frm.Controls.Add(ctrl);
    pg.DesignerInitialize();
    pg.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    string strHTML = stringWrite.ToString();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strHTML);
```

This is called on pageload event. So i am printing the .aspx page in print.aspx. So i want this content should be in the static page width.

Comment: it doesn't really matter, you can change it from out side using JS like explained in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Width specified inside window.open() function will only set width of the popup window. If you want to change the width of the page then you should try changing the width inside Print.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change width of the page using `window.open`, it only sets the window properties.

To change the `width` of the page you need to change the style of print.aspx
probably if you have to change the width of the wrapped `div` element or `body` of the page

```
var newwindow = window.open('Print.aspx');
var elem = newwindow.document.getElementById('my-id');
elem.style.width = 'XYZpx'
```

P.S. :- The above code will only work if the new window has the same protocol, domain and port. If it's on another domain, you can't do this for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

In case which you're using that page only with the window.open method then set the width of the page respectively hard-coded, otherwise, inject the size while opening the page using window.open.

**How to inject while opening:**

[Access child window elements from parent window using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9601933/952310)
(Notice to security issues on [Cross-origin resource sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing))

In short:

```
var childWindow = window.open('Print.aspx','PrintMe','width=900,resizable=1,scrollbars=1');
childWindow.document.getElementById('someDivId').style.width = '400px';
```

Or access it at the server-side:

```
HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();
frm.style = ; //
```

[read here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontrol.style.aspx)

**How to set it hard-coded:**

Width of which element in the window you want to change?
`body`?`div`?

I guess you you're taking about the `margin` left & right of your page's `body`.

try insert the following style block to your `head` tag:

```
<style>
body{margin: 0 10px 0 10px;}
</style>
```

where `10px` is the left and right margin.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
window.resizeTo(x,y);
```

For Instance:

```
function resizeWindow() 
{           
    // you can get height and width from serverside as well      
    var width=400;
    var height=400; 
    window.resizeTo(width,height);           
}
```

On onload() event of body call the function

```
<body onload="resizeWindow()" >
   body of page
</body>
```