# How to read the meta title of a popup window in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm opening a new window to let users connect their Twitter account. Is it possible to read the meta title or URL of the created window? (it's within the same domain/origin)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <button onclick="openWin()">Open newWindow</button>

        <script>
            var myWindow;

            function openWin() {
                myWindow = window.open("https://www.example.com/waiting.php", 
                    "myWindow", "width=600, height=400");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access child window elements from parent window using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600969/access-child-window-elements-from-parent-window-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myWindow` will behave the same as your typical `window` object, eg:

```
myWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].text
```

or

```
myWindow.location.href
```

Although due to the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), if create a new window from a different domain, you will not be able to access its members. That is, if your site is `foo.com` and you use `myWindow = window.open("bar.net")`, you will not be able to access its members or query its DOM for good security reasons.

Comment: I can't get it to work. All I get is a *about:blank*. This is the function: `function openWin() {
myWindow = window.open("https://www.example.com", "myWindow", "width=600, height=400");     
alert(myWindow.location.href);
}
` Any ideas?

Comment: It's alerting about:blank because when you call alert, the window hasn't finished loading yet (since JS runs so much faster than a web page is able to load). If you wait until the window is finished loading and then call alert then stuff should happen. I suspect it will be an error saying "Permission denied to access property 'href'" if you are still trying to load www.example.com, because of the same-origin policy I referenced in my answer. You can only access members of window objects that share the **same domain name and protocol**, unless you want to write your own browser

Comment: If I put the `alert(myWindow.location.href);` in a seperate function, it's not working either. The *example.com* is the same domain as the origin btw. Is there a working example I could check out?

Comment: here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v6HRb/2/
Try replacing the relative href "/" with other domains from your own site and troubleshoot what your problem might be.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the jsfiddle is being run in an iframe with a different location.href than the window it appears to be in, but the same concept still applies.

Comment: Thank you very much! (It was a httpS/http problem.)